# Why is the 'Order' button greyed out when I try to buy a car on GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I'm having trouble buying a car in the online shop. I've bought cars on it before with no trouble but now it's a grey order button.

Yes I have a 10 car garage. Could anyone help?

Comment: Do you have enough money? Enough space?

Answer (score 8):

You need to pick the colour for your car first!