# Unable to buy any of the free cars on GTA Online Criminal Enterprise Pack

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Maybe I'm missing something, I see an email on the ifruit phone describing the items in the Criminal Enterprise Pack.

Says that certain cars, properties, etc will all free. So i go to choose the Grotti Turismo, on legendarymotorsports site, and it says FREE but I cant order it, because the Order button is disabled or blocked.  It just doesn't respond.  Also, none of the other "FREE" cars can be ordered either.

I made space in my 10 car garage, so thats not the issue.  My 10-car garage is currently empty in my primary apartment.

Playing as funkdubious on xbox one.  I have about $1m gta dollars so is that the bug, not having enough GTA $ to purchase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you choose a color for the car? You have to pick one of the available colors near the order button for it to be enabled. I consider that an interface usability issue, as it is not intuitive that one color must be chosen. A color could come pre-selected by default, or they should give a hint near the button to avoid the issue. I fell for that myself, and I know that others did, too. See related post:

- [Why is the 'Order' button greyed out when I try to buy a car on GTA Online?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138254/why-is-the-order-button-greyed-out-when-i-try-to-buy-a-car-on-gta-online)

Comment: Chose this as answer because it adds additional context to the problem, usability.  And yes that was my problem, no color selected, although I wanted black and it looks like black is selected.  I could swear I tried changing the color at one point to order the car but I'm not sure now.

Answer (score 1):

The [Criminal Enterprise Starter Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/771300) is a paid pack that cost $39.99:

[image: RGSC Store]

You can see what the pack contains on [this Wiki article](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Criminal_Enterprise_Starter_Pack).

If you already bought the pack and/or you have enough GTA$ on your game account, remember to choose a car color before pressing "buy":

[image: Buying the Banshee without choosing any color]

Comment: I think the OP has bought the package (or got it somehow) as he implies that the price tags on the items say "FREE" to him. If you don't own the package, then the game shows regular price for these particular items. But it's good to know all about that package anyway. (+1)

Comment: Yeah, is better to explain for other users that don't know what the CESP is and/or they don't have it.

Comment: Yip that was the problem, no color selected, although I wanted black and it looks like black is selected.  I could swear I tried changing the color at one point to order the car but I'm not sure now.